# Вывод данных в виде таблицы

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Как можно вывести данные из массива по 3 элемента в одну строку в RectJS?
Такой должен быть результат вывода:

```
<div class="Row">
  <div class="col element">1</div>
  <div class="col element">2</div>
  <div class="col element">3</div>
</div>
<div class="Row">
  <div class="col element">4</div>
  <div class="col element">5</div>
  <div class="col element">6</div>
</div>
<div class="Row">
  <div class="col element">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Row extends Component {
    render() {
        const {cells} = this.props

        return (
            <div className="Row">
                {cells.map( (c) =>
                    <div className="col element" key={c.id}>
                        {c.value}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class Table extends Component {
    render() {
        const {rows} = this.props

        return (
            <div className='table'>
                {rows.map( (r, k) =>
                    <Row cells={r} key={k} />
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


// Использование
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            data: [
                [{id: 1, value: 1}, {id: 2, value: 2}],
                [{id: 3, value: 3}]
            ]
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Table rows={this.state.data}/>
        )
    }
}
```

**P.S.** 
Если у вас будет статическая таблица, которая никогда не меняется, то в качестве ключа (`key`) можно использовать индекс элемента в массиве, но если данные в таблицу поступают динамические и могут меняться, то тогда лучше поменять структуру на что-нибудь в таком роде

```
[{id: 1, value: 1}, {id: 2, value: 2} ... ]
```

и использовать качестве `key` `id` элемента, а не его индекс 
Прочитать подробнее можно тут (EN: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318#.j9101ib23)

Comment: Вот у меня и такая структура. [{},{},{}....{}]. Не могу изменить код ваш, на такую структуру ругается.

Comment: @AlekseyTkachenko, поправил

Comment: Вы используете на каждый Row - массив с элементами. А я имел ввиду, что у меня один массив с 10 элементами. И мне нужно по 3 элемента в Row вносить. Извините, что не так объяснил вопрос.